How to determine approximate factor (i.e. modulus-to-(bound of)noise ratio) of LWE in advaned primitives is sub-exponential or polynomial?
In advanced primitives like circuit (policy) ABE [BGG+'Eurocrypt2014] or IPFE [ACGU'Asiacrypt2020, appedix A] based on lattices, parameters setting is quite puzzling and vague (for me).
(Parameter inequalities seem to mutually depend on each other on left and right-hand sides of the inequalities! For example, something like $a<b\cdot c$ and $b<a\cdot d$)
Knowing approximating factor (i.e. modulus-to-(bound of)-noise ratio) of LWE gives us better understanding of security level of these advanced primitives when we're comparing them with each others. In some papers like [BGG+'Eurocrypt2014, page 6 and page 9] approximating factor of LWE is explained explicitly and rather well. Whereas in other papers like [ACGU'Asiacrypt2020, appendix A] authors don't mention it.
My question is "How to find out the approximating factor of LWE in such situations where parameter settings are quite complicated?", particularly "What is the approxoimating factor of LWE for IPFE of [ACGU'Asiacrypt2020, appedix A]?"

Evaluating that paper is somewhat difficult, as they are somewhat slopping in their writing.
I started reading on page 43, and it is possible the following is resolved if you read their paper closely enough (I haven't), though reading the section marked "Lattice Preliminaries" closely leads to the following confusion.
It is stated that $\mathsf{LWE}_{q,\alpha,n}$ is reducible to worst-case lattice problems in dimension $n$ if $q\alpha \geq \Omega(\sqrt{n})$.
From brief skimming, $\mathsf{LWE}_{q,\alpha,n}$ doesn't appear to be defined in this paper though. Something close is defined, namely $\mathsf{LWE}_{q,\chi,n}$ is defined just before Proposition 4.3.
Immediately after this, the notation $\mathsf{LWE}_{q, \overline{\Psi}_\alpha}$ is used to cite a preexisting result (though is not defined in this work).
This is to say that there are three competing notations for a particular instantiation of the LWE assumption used within $\approx 3$ pages (namely pages 25-27 specifically), and only one is defined (and then never used again).
It is plausible that by $\mathsf{LWE}_{q,\alpha,n}$ they mean $\mathsf{LWE}_{q,\overline{\Psi}_\alpha,n}$, though even this requires knowing the definition of $\overline{\Psi}_\alpha$, which while common among some early work in lattices, is uncommon lately. At a high level, I would assume they mean a discrete Gaussian of standard deviation $\sigma = O(\alpha q)$. You'll see below they have a different expression for $\sigma$, but it is at least within a small polynomial factor of being what my guess was.
Anyway, even after the above (which is consistent with prior work, though not explained well here), there are issues with understanding their statements.
The following is Theorem 4.10, which is key to answering your question.

Theorem 4.10: Let $n$ be the security parameter, $q \geq 2K\ell \sqrt{\ell}V\omega(\log^2n)$, $\sigma = 2C\alpha q(\sqrt{m} + \sqrt{n} + \sqrt{\ell})$,
$\rho\geq \omega(\sqrt{\log n})$, $m = 2n \log q$, ${\color{red}\alpha} ≤ \frac{σ}{
2C{\color{\red}\alpha} q(\sqrt{m}+\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{\ell})}$ , then the scheme from Fig. 11 is AD-IND-secure in the
random-oracle model, assuming that $\mathsf{LWE}_{q,\alpha,n}$ is hard.

The issue is with bounding the parameter $\alpha$.
(The inverse of) this is probably the approximation factor you are interested in, and you want to know if it is a polynomial in $n$, or sub-exponential in $n$.
I say probably because their unexplained notation for $\mathsf{LWE}_{q,\alpha,n}$ leaves this up in the air, but it is my best guess.
If we knew that a certain family of $(q(n),\sigma(n),\rho(n),m(n),\alpha(n))$ yielded a secure (measured by the security parameter $n$) scheme, we could then look at how $\alpha(n)^{-1}$ scales with $n$ to answer your question.
The issue is that the way they suggest setting $\alpha$ seems to have a typo, due to the presence of $\alpha$ on both of the sides of the bound quoted above.
I haven't read carefully enough to be sure this is a typo, but the other sloppiness in defining $\mathsf{LWE}_{q,\alpha,n}$ leads me to believe that it might be hard to get a reliable answer to this without checking their computations in some detail.

I think based on lower bound for discrete Gaussian parameter of noise re-randomization (of LWE) technique, $\sigma\geq2\alpha q\cdot\Omega(\rho(\sqrt m+\sqrt n+\sqrt\ell))$, there must not be an $\alpha$ in the denominator of upper bound for $\alpha$. Now if we get number of vector coordinates $\ell=\mathsf{poly}(n)$، what will be the answer?
